# I converted my html website into node js, but my js files are not working correctly. They are running, but there are some errors in them

Tags: javascript, node.js, ejs

MY Node js is working correctly  (**phenomit.com** This is my design website its in HTML)

**My errors are:**

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'each')at waypoints.min.js:7:9157

at waypoints.min.js:7:9567jquery.counterup.min.js:8 Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined

at jquery.counterup.min.js:8:910jquery.magnific-popup.min.js:4 Uncaught TypeError: a is not a function

at jquery.magnific-popup.min.js:4:374
at jquery.magnific-popup.min.js:4:73

at jquery.magnific-popup.min.js:4:147custom.js:4 Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
at custom.js:4:24

I have shared the code in my git

[image]

https://github.com/GoD-ATHEN/Phentom

```
const express = require('express');
    const app = express();
    const mysql = require('mysql');
    const router = express.Router();
    const path = require('path');
    const ifl = path.join(__dirname, '/views/assets/')
    
    app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
    app.use('/assets',express.static(ifl));
    
    //CONNECTION CONFIGURATION
    var con = mysql.createConnection({
        host: "localhost",
        user: "root",
        password: "",
        database: "phentom"
       });
    
    app.get("/contact", (req, res)=>{
        res.render("contact");
    });
    
    app.get('/askquestion', (req, res) =>{
        con.query(`INSERT INTO contactq (name, email, subject, massage) VALUES ('${req.query.name}', '${req.query.email}', '${req.query.subject}', '${req.query.message}')`, function (err, result, fields) {
          if (err) throw err;
          res.redirect('https://phenomit.com/');
        });
    });
    
    app.listen(3000);
```

Comment: from the looks of it, i think that your ```jquery``` is not loaded in your page and all of the error is because of it. how did you include ```jquery``` in your webpage?

Comment: Am using a middel ware to run my css and js

const ifl = path.join(__dirname, '/views/assets/')
app.use('/assets',express.static(ifl));

Comment: jquery is not included in your view. check your footer.ejs again.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so I don't know what happened. I just added a JQuery CDN link in my footer, and now it's all working.

`<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>`

This is the link

Answer (score 0):

For me it works. I downloaded from github, ran `npm install` and then:

- Did you run `node index.js` ?
- Did you visit http://localhost:3000/contact ?
- jQuery - please uncomment this line `<script src="assets/js/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>`

That's it. it works.

Comment: Yeah, it looks okay, but some animations and mouse pointer animations are not working. Please check my website, phenomit.com.

Comment: homepage of your website has jquery and hence not giving any errors. i tested it on chrome.

Comment: When I run the contacts page in node js, I get the jQuery error. My website is working fine.